# What does it mean when an extends clause in a generic type varaible has an assignment

Tags: typescript, generics

Digging through the interfaces related to react I came accross this snippet

```
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
    type: T;
    props: P;
    key: Key | null;
}
```

I do not understand the second part of the union in the second generic argument:

```
JSXElementConstructor<any> = string
```

What does the asignment do there?

Comment: It's a type parameter default. If you don't specify a type argument for that type parameter, the type parameter defaults to `string`. Here's how you parse that: `T` is the name of the type parameter. `extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any>` is the `extends` clause on it. `=` says there's a default, and `string` is the default.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, ok, I got confused by the union. I thought it was a union of three things one of which was `JSXElementConstructor<any> = string` When in fact it was merely a union of two things